# Is there a way to capture RTMP-stream and output it to SDI?

Tags: video, streaming, sdi, rtmp

Is there any way to capture an RTMP stream and output it to SDI?

Here is my situation: We specialize in producing local sports for web streaming. Occasionally we are asked to deliver a stream to a local TV-station. Paying for uplink truck and the whole satellite thing is way beyond our budget.

I'm not really familiar with IP-based workflows, that's why capturing RTMP-stream was my first idea.

Comment: Try 'Wireshark'.................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succesfully used Wirecast software in the past to bring in two RTMP sources and switch between them for live streaming an event from two different venues across the country. It worked wonderfully. You could then use a cheap BlackMagic device to get that out of your pc into an SDI feed.

Wirecast sources: http://www.telestream.net/wirecast/devices.htm#ip

Answer (score 1):

I found this rack mount device called [DVEO D-Streamer IP/DIG](http://dveo.com/pdf/D-Streamer-IP-Datasheet.pdf). One of DVEO's press relises announced $4000 price for the device.

Inputs: HTTP Live (HLS), UDP, RTP, RTSP, HTTP, RTMP (Open Flash), MMS.
Output: SD/HD-SDI.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's plenty of software available to capture an RTMP stream available on the internet, although I personally have not tried any of it because I don't have a legitimate reason to do so.  However, to output to SDI, you might be interested in something like [this.](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/892451-REG/Blackmagic_Design_bdlkulsdzminmon_Ultrastudio_Mini_Monitor.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest bet is to simply play back the RTMP stream on a system with SDI output.  Don't even need special software, just full screen it and let it rip.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the RTMP stream to a local file using rtmpdump for example (http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/), which is the library (but you can download it precompiled as well) that originally cracked the encryption on RTMP, which is a proprietary Adobe protocol.

Then you can use any other software, like ffmpeg, to output the file to SDI *WHILE* rtmpdump is still dumping the stream to the file in question.

Answer (score -1):

These days there are a few IRD's and STB's that can input RTMP/HLS and output on HDMI.

The popular Amino A140 can do HLS to HDMI. 
For a more pro solution the [NOVUS-RD](https://www.advanceddigital.ca/products/receivers_decoders/novus-rd_h264_and_mpeg2_hd_sd_decoder/) can do RTMP/HLS to SDI, HDMI, and/or CVBS.

Comment: Consider explaining your solution a bit more. Not everyone knows what an IRD or an STB is. You may want to expand the acronyms and give links to reference material.